# Why doesn't Ansible win_regedit change a Windows registry value?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to enable RDP on a Windows 11 machine with Ansible and its win_regedit module. The idea is to set a value that is to change a value from its default of 1 to 0, which enables RDP.
The task in my playbook looks like this:

```
  - name: Set Registry key
    ansible.windows.win_regedit:
      path: 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server'
      name: 'fDenyTSConnections'
      value: 0
      type: dword
```

However, when I run it, Ansible doesn't change anything and reports it as OK. -vvv output for ansible-playbook looks like this (I have verified the value is set to '1', i.e. the undesired state):

```
ok: [win11test] => {
    "changed": false,
    "data_changed": false,
    "data_type_changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "data": null,
            "delete_key": true,
            "hive": null,
            "name": "0",
            "path": "HKLM:\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Terminal Server",
            "state": "present",
            "type": "dword",
            "value": 0
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a bit stumped here. There's nothing [in the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_regedit_module.html) to suggest I'm doing anything wrong.
The WinRM connection to the host seems to allow this just fine - I can run a PSSession from a Windows host, using the same credentials, and run the equivalent Powershell just fine. The code is:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server' -name "fDenyTSConnections" -value 0
```

Anyone got an idea why Ansible thinks there's nothing to do here, and what I need to change about my task?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to this specific question, but i found this on Google while researching my similar problem, as might others.

If the `name` value is surrounded by `{` and `}` like a lot of keys are, its essential to double-quote the name, otherwise Ansible tries to expand it as a variable, and it hits the wrong key.

```yaml
- name: Show My Computer (1)
  ansible.windows.win_regedit:
    path: HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu
    name: "{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
    data: 0
    type: dword
```

is good.

```yaml
- name: Show My Computer (1)
  ansible.windows.win_regedit:
    path: HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu
    name: {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
    data: 0
    type: dword
```

is bad.